# How to write regression equation for logistic regression model based on categorical data

Tags: regression, logistic

Here's an example of a formula:
Intelligence ~ SEX + AGE + SCHOOLING

How would I write out the regression equation for the above if for example schooling had 3 categories? E.g. High School, Undergraduate, Postgraduate, as well as SEX with 2 categories? E.g. Male, Female.

Comment: Welcome to CV! This can be done using a design matrix, or if you want to avoid linear algebra, by using $k-1$ dummy variables (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_(statistics)#ANCOVA_models), where $k$ is the number of categories of the variable.

Answer (score 2):

Because you said logistic regression, assume intelligence has two level: high and low.

Define: $Y = 1$ if intelligence is high, = 0 otherwise

$X_1 = 1$ for male, = 0 for female

$X_2 = \text{age}$

$X_3 = 1$ for High school, = 0 for other school

$X_4 = 1$ for Undergraduate, = 0 for other school

The model is:
$$\log\left(\frac {\pi}{1-\pi}\right) = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2 + \beta_3X_3 +\beta_4X_4,$$ where $\Pr(Y=1) = \pi$.